# Can I use "post" to mean "comment"?

Tags: word-usage

I am used to say *post* to mean either a question/answer or a comment posted on a Stack Exchange site, influenced from the fact that *post* seems to me a verb I could use for answers and comments.

Looking at the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/post_1?q=post) (the fifth definition), I read the following definition.

> a message sent to a discussion group on the Internet; a piece of writing that forms part of a blog

On the given examples, I interpret *That forum does not allow posts from nonmembers.* as referring to either a forum post or replies to a forum post done from other users (which in the Drupal CMS I use are comments).

Can I use *post* to include also comments, or should *post* just be used for what in Stack Exchange sites are questions and answers?

Comment: This is more about distinguishing between an initial statement **posted** online - in whatever forum - and responses to it. A response may simply be a brief comment or a lengthy rebuttal/analysis etc. What constitutes a post is then often just a matter of opinion.. In short, it's a grey area.

Comment: A convention has arisen on many sites of not calling comments "posts". You should follow the accepted terminology used by other users of the site so that you won't be misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one. It sounds correct, but I personally am used to hearing for example: "a comment on a post". This would imply that "post" is the main object, like your question. Comment would be an extension of that main object.

I looked it up too and it doesn't say that it is limited to the main "posts" like I said before. It can apparently be "content published online", so now having this makes me think that "post" can be used for comments as they are also online content.

I would personally still use "comment" just for my own comfort.

Answer (score 0):

A post (the noun), is not a comment.

You can post a comment, but a comment is not a post.

Comment: That seems a bit cryptic. If you can post it why is it not classified as a post I wonder?